# TComboBox – странное поведение OnMouseEnter/OnMouseLeave

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

Когда мышь движется по текстовому полю ComboBox-а (а не по стрелочке), то происходит не единичный вызов `OnMouseEnter`, а затем `OnMouseLeave`, а череда непрерывных вызовов `OnMouseEnter`/`OnMouseLeave` (похоже, что по паре `OnMouseEnter`/`OnMouseLeave` на каждое перемещение мыши).

Такое происходит только если свойство Style равно `csDropDown`.
Если свойство Style равно `csDropDownList`, то поведение стандартное.

Подскажите, возможно ли как-то исправить?

Comment: Похоже, что это не баг, а фича =) В XE5 происходит тоже самое. Расскажите для чего вам эти события, может придумаем как исправить.

Comment: Я хотел повесить на это событие аналог TApplication.OnHint. Т.е. когда курсор входит в границы контрола, то в определенном поле отображается текстовая строка.

Comment: Можно по событию проверять что написано в этом вашем поле и менять его содержимое только при необходимости.

Answer (score 1):

```
protected procedure OnMouseEnter( 
    e: MouseEventArgs
); override;
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?